# How do Permanent Magnet Generators Work?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Why we don't use [this](http://www.ask.com/question/how-do-permanent-magnet-generators-work) in our houses to generate the electricity? Isn't the electricity generated by the magnets strong enough? Why do we have to pay for electricity if we can just create it by pushing the magnets attached to a rotor of the generator?

Comment: Many people do use them most commonly as wind generators.  Permanent magnet generators are just one type of option, there are various types of generators.

Comment: there are very strong magnets that are able to hold a person if positioned well. Why not use this magnets to repel each other to achieve spinning the generator?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get 'free' energy, as [energy cannot be created or destroyed.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy) All 'free energy' devices are scams.

In order to generate electricity with a generator, you have to provide energy. If you turn the crank manually, that energy comes from your food, which comes from plants, who get their energy from the sun, which gets its energy from nuclear fusion.

If you are curious about how generators work, you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator).

Comment: well, the energy that I put into a generator is the energy coming from the magnetic field, magnets. And Yes, cannot be created or destroyed but it can be transformed...

Comment: there are very strong magnets that are able to hold a person if positioned well. Why not use this magnets to repel each other to achieve spinning the generator?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac Gravity is capable of holding objects to the ground - why can't you generate energy with gravity? Because while a falling ball gains speed (kinetic) energy, that is due to the work gravity does on the ball. If you want to bring back the ball to its original position (before falling) you will have to perform work to get it there. It's just an exchange of potential energy. There's no 'free lunch'.

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac The magnets do no work, they simply *redirect* your work, just like a pulley.

Comment: but you do generate energy with gravity! What about the water power plants?

Comment: The water evaporates, forms clouds, rains down in the mountains and flows back to the sea as a river. Indirectly you're still getting your energy from the sun.

Comment: no, the river flows through the turbines and spins them thanks to the gravity. The turbines spins generators and create electricity...

Comment: How does the water get to the source of the river?

Comment: it is going away from the source because of gravity...

Comment: Yes, but does it get TO the source? It doesn't appear out of nothing.

Comment: yes it does! Falling from the skies and penetrating inside of the soil forming the source. All is done thanks to gravity. Sun doesn't matter because if there is no gravity, water wouldn't fall down.

Comment: Do you understand http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Watercyclesummary.jpg, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cycle ?

Comment: And do you also understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity and "the production of electrical power through the use of the gravitational force of falling or flowing water."?

Comment: No, I don't. Can you explain how water gets in 'the skies'?

Comment: and can you tell me how it gets down on earth?

Comment: As you say, gravity. But how does water get high in the sky in the first place?

Comment: but it's still the gravitational force that creates the electrical power. The steam isn't the primary force and can't be compared to the power of gravity.

Comment: ' The steam isn't the primary force and can't be compared to the power of gravity.'  Can you explain?

Comment: ok, after reading your comments more closely, I think I understand what you are trying to say. The thing is though is that the magnets holds the phenomena similar to a nuclear fusion in the sun. So this power could be used for creating the energy. Or if we can go on and on, where the nuclear fusion is getting the energy for creating the fusion and excess heat?

Comment: Then you ultimately end up asking 'where does matter/energy itself come from?'. Search for 'lawrence krauss something from nothing' on youtube, he explains it far better than I ever could.

Comment: oh, please don't mention this amateur who ridicule himself with contradictions.

Answer (score 0):

And to expand on Kvothe's answer, the cost of the extra food you would need would exceed the cost of the regular fuel that you save.  In addition, who wants to spend their life turning a generator?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that... http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2305

Comment: Dang, how could I have forgotten superpowers?